# Selecting slot text in Custom Element Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, custom-element

I made a simple copy-paste component with regular html/css/js. I've tried to turn it into a web component and can no longer get the copy-paste behaviour to work.

The markup inside the shadow DOM is basically

```
<span contenteditable="true">
  <slot></slot>
</span>
<button>Copy</button>
```

The Javascript:

```
class CopyPaste extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(copyPasteTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    let copyButton = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    let textToCopy = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('span');

    function selectElementContents(el) {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }

    function copyText() {
      selectElementContents(textToCopy);
      document.execCommand('copy');
    }

    copyButton.addEventListener('click', copyText);
    textToCopy.addEventListener('click', copyText);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('copy-paste', CopyPaste);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, the `textToCopy` variable refers to the `<slot>` element, with no text inside.

If you want to get the ditributed node form the light DOM, of the `<copy-paste>` element, you should use the [`assignedNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedNodes) method of the `<slot>` element:

```
let textToCopy = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').assignedNodes()[0];
```

PS: note that the `contenteditable` attribute may not work as you expect in your given example.

Comment: "note that the contenteditable attribute may not work as you expect in your given example" - it worked! :)

Comment: Consider using `{flatten: true}` so that this still works when `<slot>` is filled from a parent's slot: `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').assignedNodes({flatten: true})[0];` (this is in the documentation linked to in the answer above)