# updating slot text in Custom Element Shadow DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, web-component

Thanks to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311245/selecting-slot-text-in-custom-element-shadow-dom) I can select the text of a slot in my custom element.

I am wondering what is the proper way to update the slot text with javascript?

Can this work?

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').assignedNodes()[0].innerHTML = 'New text';
```

or this one

```
 this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').assignedNodes()[0]. textContent = 'New text';
```

And should I even be updating the slot content directly with JS inside the component or is there some religious rule that slots should always be populated by the host only?

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are working and are mostly equivalent as long as your element content is only text.

Howerver the second one is better at handling some special, HTML-specific characters, like `<` or `>`.

```js
div.textContent = 'to<to'
```

```html
<div id=div></div>
```